# SharePoint 2010 Development Setup

Tags: development, debugging, vmware

Is it possible to develop in Visual Studio on the host machine while F5 deploying/debugging a SharePoint WSP to a VM with SharePoint 2010 installed?  I have had significant issues with Visual Studio, SharePoint, ReSharper, etc. when developing in a VM and I would like to take advantage of the new SSD's and RAM of my host computer.

Does anyone have a similar setup or am i stuck with installing visual studio in each of my VM's?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The F5 deploying/debugging is not going to work the way you intend it to. 
I have tried this myself and just ended up installing VS2010 on the server. 
Here is a discussion surrounding the question from TechNet: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopmentprevious/thread/c7a6cb80-ac22-484c-a83e-09d94b987954

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Its unfortunate, but hopefully this new rig will perform better.

Comment: Antyime! It would have been really nice if it integrated nicely...